# Bad context binding within service

Tags: angular, this, rxjs, observable, angular2-http

I'm trying to set the `token` attribute on my `AuthenticationService`.

Here's my code:

authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Login } from '../../+authentication/shared/models'
import { config } from '../config'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string
  private _isConnected = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
  isConnected$ = this._isConnected.asObservable()

  constructor (private http: Http) {
    const currentToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentToken'))
    if (currentToken) {
      this.token = currentToken.token 
      this._isConnected.next(true) // work
    }
  }

  login (login: Login): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(config.BASE_URL + '/auth/login', login)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        if (response.json() && response.json().success) {
          const token = response.json() && response.json().token
          this.token = token// don't do the work
          this._isConnected.next(true) // don't do the work neither

          localStorage.setItem('currentToken', JSON.stringify({token}))

          return {
            success: true
          }
        } else if (response.json() && response.json().message) {
          return {
            success: false,
            message: response.json().message
          }
        }
      })
  }

  logout (): void {
    this.token = null
    this._isConnected.next(false) // work
    localStorage.removeItem('currentToken') // work
  }

  logToken (): void {
    console.log(this.token) // null
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentToken')) // {"token":"eyJhb..."}

    // do the work
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentToken')
    console.log(this.token)

    // do the work too
    this._isConnected.next(true)
  }
}
```

Called from `login.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../shared/services'

import { Login } from '../shared/models/index'

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {
  public login: Login = new Login('test@test.fr', 'test')
  public authError: string

  constructor (
    private router: Router,
    private as: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    if (as.getToken()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']) // This work !! That's not 
    }
  }

  onSubmit () {
    this.as.login(this.login)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.success) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']) // working
        } else if (result.message) {
          this.authError = result.message // working
        }
      })
  }
}
```

At the end of `authentication.service.ts`, you can see the `logToken` function:

```
logToken (): void {
    console.log(this.token) // null
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('currentToken')) // {"token":"eyJhb..."}

    // do the work
    this.token = localStorage.getItem('currentToken')
    console.log(this.token)

    // do the work too
    this._isConnected.next(true)
  }
```

I call it manually from my app component by clicking a button in the navbar, and the token property is never set, unless I reload the page, in that case it's set by the constructor of the service, who gets it from LocalStorage.

Please tell me why the let don't want to work, I used the arrow-function to bind it but it seems it's not working.

Thanks in advance

SherlockStd

**EDIT**

I tried to delegate the response handling to a private method to see if the this binding is better, but it's still not working (authentication.service.ts):

```
  login (login: Login): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(config.BASE_URL + '/auth/login', login)
      .map((response: Response) => this.handleResponse(response))
  }

  private handleResponse (response: Response) {
    if (response.json() && response.json().success) {
          // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
      const token = response.json() && response.json().token
      this.token = token

      localStorage.setItem('currentToken', JSON.stringify({token}))

      return {
        success: true
      }
    } else if (response.json() && response.json().message) {
      return {
        success: false,
        message: response.json().message
      }
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 2**

I logged the `this` keyword from authentication.service.ts, inside the `login()` and `logToken()` functions.
It return an AuthenticationService each times, containing the same attributes but into the login function it contains the `token` attribute, which is lossed outside this function.

Comment: Isn't the problem in `const token = response.json() && response.json().token`? I think `&&` makes the expression always a boolean `true/false`.

Comment: ... The problem is very likely in `this.as.login(this.login)` because there you're losing `this` context, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback. Use `this.as.login(data => this.login(data))` instead.

Comment: @martin why would he be losing the `this` context? `this.as.login(this.login)` is still in the global context at this point? Also won't, `this.login(data)` will just error as `data` will be null at this point?

Comment: what do u mean "don't do the work" ? do u see exception or what? do console.log(this) before "don't do the work". what does it print?

Comment: You should have done at least some debugging yourself. Can you tell us what have done and what is the outcome? 'Don't do the work' is confusing.

Comment: @martin you should provide it as an answer so that OP can mark it as accepted

Comment: @SherlockStd Did you try the two things I mentioned in the the first comnets?

Comment: @martin for the const token definition this is definitely not the problem, the response.json() is used to determine if it's undefined to avoid error "Can't read property 'token' of `undefined`"

Comment: @martin @Zze is right `this.as.login(data => this.login(data))` can't work, this.login is just a object btw

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova Don't do the work mean it doesn't set the `token` attribute on my service, no exception, nothing, but when I try to read the `this.token` after that, it's `undefined`

Comment: @all see the edits for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of research, I finally found the source of this problem.

I was declaring the same service in the parent (`app.module.ts`) and the child (`authentication.module.ts`) modules (see the structure below).

```
src/
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts <== provide AuthenticationService
├── app.routes.ts <== load authentication.module with router.loadChildren()
│
├── +authentication/
│   ├── authentication.component.html
│   ├── authentication.component.ts
│   ├── authentication.module.ts <== provide AuthenticationService
│   ├── authentication.routes.ts <== expose a route to login component
│   └── login
│       ├── login.component.html
│       └── login.component.ts <== using service's methods here don't work
│
└── shared/
    └── services/
        ├── authentication.service.ts
        └── base.service.ts
```

I can't understand why it influenced the `this` binding, but it's working now, and I opened an [issue on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16652) because I think an error should throw up in that case.

Thanks for your help.